# How to detect what screen orientation is "natural" for a BlackBerry device?

Tags: java, blackberry

Prior to BlackBerry OS 4.7, screens could only have one orientation, so adapting your app to the screen was simply a matter screen pixel width, height. (And to some extent, DPI, but that didn't matter as much then.)

Later BlackBerry models have orientation sensors, and their screens can be in any rotation depending on how you hold them.

On a BlackBerry 9800 for instance (OS 6.0) I can check for orientation NORTH.

But given that I didn't know from looking at the screen that the 9800 has the BlackBerry logo on one of its short sides, how would my app know?

Another way to put the question:  is the BlackBerry logo above a short or long side?

Yet another way: is the device naturally a portrait or landscape device?

```
switch(Display.getOrientation()) {
       case Display.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
          Dialog.alert("Screen orientation is landscape"); break;
       case Display.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
          Dialog.alert("Screen orientation is portrait"); break;
       case Display.ORIENTATION_SQUARE:
          Dialog.alert("Screen orientation is square"); break;
       default:
          Dialog.alert("Screen orientation is not known"); break;
}
```

only checks the current orientation, it does not say for instance if you are holding the device upside down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Orientation vs. direction problem](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Orientation-vs-direction-problem/td-p/328311)

Comment: Yes, but will that help?  A comment from that code:   // Assumes portrait orientation is DIRECTION_NORTH.  +1 though for spending time on this question.

Comment: Accepting because I don't think it gets any better than that.